# MySQL school Project - Problems with Join

Tags: mysql, join

I’m working on a school project, where we are tasked to create a database for a construction company. I have created the database and inserted all my data. 
But I’m having difficulties solving one of the queries that are required.

Please be aware that all column and table names are in Danish.

I need to create a query that tells me which department (Table `Afdelinger.id`) that only sells houses with one floor (table `HusType.Etageantal`). There is only one department that does that, and that is dept 07(AfdId).

No matter how I create the query, I always get all departments that sells one floor houses or nothing, but those departments are also selling 2 floor houses. So my query should only output AfdId 07.
I tried these queries, but they are not giving me the correct result

```
select etageantal, id, udbyder.ModelNr from hustype
inner join udbyder
on  id = id
where Etageantal like 1 = Etageantal not like 2
group by id;

select * from hustype
left join udbyder on hustype.modelnr = udbyder.modelnr
where Etageantal like 1
union
select * from hustype
right outer join udbyder on hustype.modelnr = udbyder.modelnr
where Etageantal like 1
order by id;
```

The table `Udbyder` are a junction table for `HusType` and `Afdelinger`.

```
Create table Afdelinger(
AfdId int not null,
Navn varchar(45) not null,
PostNr int not null,
primary key(AfdId),
foreign key(PostNr) references PostNummer(PostNr)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


Create Table HusType(
ModelNr int(3) not null,
ModelNavn varchar(10) not null,
Kvm int(3) not null,
Etageantal int(1) not null, 
primary key(ModelNr)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


Create table Udbyder(
HusPrisAfd decimal not null,
Id int not null,
ModelNr int(3) not null,
primary key(HusPrisAfd, Id),
unique(HusPrisAfd),
foreign key(Id) references Afdelinger(AfdId),
foreign key(ModelNr) references HusType(ModelNr)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Here is my data

Table name = Afdelinger

```
+-------+---------------------+--------+
| AfdId | Navn                | PostNr |
+-------+---------------------+--------+
|     1 | Herning             |   7400 |
|     2 | Brønderslev         |   9800 |
|     3 | Haderslev           |   6100 |
|     4 | Højbjerg            |   8270 |
|     5 | Brabrand            |   8220 |
|     6 | Fyn                 |   5000 |
|     7 | Sjælland og Øerne   |   4000 |
+-------+---------------------+--------+
```

Tbl name = Udbyder

```
+------------+----+---------+
| HusPrisAfd | Id | ModelNr |
+------------+----+---------+
|    1175000 |  2 |     102 |
|    1250000 |  1 |     100 |
|    1275000 |  2 |     103 |
|    1350000 |  1 |     101 |
|    1375000 |  2 |     104 |
|    1450000 |  1 |     102 |
|    1550000 |  1 |     103 |
|    1575000 |  3 |     100 |
|    1600000 |  3 |     102 |
|    1650000 |  2 |     100 |
|    1675000 |  3 |     101 |
|    1700000 |  3 |     103 |
|    1750000 |  2 |     101 |
|    1800000 |  3 |     104 |
|    1941666 |  4 |     102 |
|    1978508 |  4 |     103 |
|    2000000 |  4 |     100 |
|    2015350 |  5 |     101 |
|    2052192 |  5 |     102 |
|    2089035 |  5 |     103 |
|    2100000 |  4 |     101 |
|    2125877 |  5 |     104 |
|    2199561 |  6 |     100 |
|    2236403 |  6 |     101 |
|    2273245 |  6 |     102 |
|    2310087 |  6 |     103 |
|    2346929 |  6 |     104 |
|    2420614 |  7 |     102 |
+------------+----+---------+
```

Tbl name = Hustype

```
+---------+-----------+-----+------------+
| ModelNr | ModelNavn | Kvm | Etageantal |
+---------+-----------+-----+------------+
|     100 | H-Huset   | 167 |          1 |
|     101 | U-Huset   | 176 |          1 |
|     102 | L-Huser   | 193 |          1 |
|     103 | Skagen    | 212 |          2 |
|     104 | Funkis    | 242 |          2 |
+---------+-----------+-----+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a subquery to accomplish this. First of all, you need to get all departments that sell one floor houses. You almost got it with your first query but you didn't use the inner join syntax correctly. You should use `ON hustype.ModelNr = udbyder.ModelNr` since `ModelNr` in `Udbyder` table is the foreign key that references `ModelNr` in `HusType` table according to your table definitions. Here's the correct query:

```
SELECT hustype.etageantal, udbyder.id, udbyder.ModelNr 
FROM hustype
INNER JOIN udbyder
ON hustype.ModelNr = udbyder.ModelNr
WHERE hustype.Etageantal = 1
```

You'll also get departments that sell both one floor and two floor houses with the above query. The next step is getting the id of the departments that sell two floor houses. The below query will do so:

```
SELECT udbyder.id
FROM hustype
INNER JOIN udbyder
ON hustype.ModelNr = udbyder.ModelNr
WHERE Etageantal <> 1
```

The result obtained from the above query should be eliminated from the result of the first query. You can do so by inserting the above query as the sub query to the where condition of first query using `NOT IN`. Below is the final query that will return all departments that only sell one floor houses:

```
SELECT hustype.etageantal, udbyder.id, udbyder.ModelNr 
FROM hustype
INNER JOIN udbyder
ON hustype.ModelNr = udbyder.ModelNr
WHERE hustype.Etageantal = 1
AND udbyder.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT udbyder.id
    FROM hustype
    INNER JOIN udbyder
    ON hustype.ModelNr = udbyder.ModelNr
    WHERE Etageantal <> 1
);
```

SQLFiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec673/13

Comment: You just saved my day, and helped me to better understand how joins work. Thanks alot